# How save facebook login using SharedPreferences in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I work with a flutter app and Facebook login. I try to save login with SharedPreferences but I failed with that. how can I store login on all pages. and when the close app and reopen don't need to log in again. thanks

more info
I use 
flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1
shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
test for android device

```
  bool isLoggedIn;
  var profileData;
  var facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();

  loginprefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", true);    
  } //  save facebook login

  logoutprefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", false);
  } //  save facebook login

  getprefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool("isLoggedIn");
      if (isLoggedIn == null) {
       isLoggedIn = false ;
      }
    });
  } //  get facebook login

  void onLoginStatusChanged(bool isLoggedIn, {profileData}) {
    setState(() {
      this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
      this.profileData = profileData;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getprefs();
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowMaterialGrid: false,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("login"),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.exit_to_app,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () => facebookLogin.isLoggedIn
                  .then((isLoggedIn) => isLoggedIn ? _logout() : {}),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(""),
            isLoggedIn ? _displayUserData(profileData) : _displayLoginButton(),
            Divider(),

          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }

///////////////////////
  void initiateFacebookLogin() async {
    var facebookLoginResult =
        await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);

    switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        var graphResponse = await http.get(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.height(200)&access_token=${facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token}');
        var profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);
       // print(profile.toString());
        onLoginStatusChanged(true, profileData: profile);
        break;
    }
  }

  _displayUserData(profileData) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 50.0,
          width: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: NetworkImage(
                profileData['picture']['data']['url'],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 28.0),
        Text(
          "Welcome : ${profileData['name']}",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _displayLoginButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Login with Facebook"),
      onPressed: () {
        initiateFacebookLogin();
        loginprefs();      
      },
    );
  }

  _logout() async {
    await facebookLogin.logOut();
    onLoginStatusChanged(false);
    logoutprefs();
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need SharedPreferences to do that. The flutter_facebook package already handles the persisten session. You only need to call `FacebookLogin().login(//the parameters you want)` as if was the first time. The package itself will know if the user is already logged so  will return a Logged Facebook Login Status

Comment: No. I don't think that